# Krull dimensions and regular sequences

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, krull-dimension

I am trying to understand if a certain condition on quotient rings is sufficient for a sequence to be regular. Here is the setting:

Let $\mathbb{C}[u_1,...,u_n]$ be the ring of regular functions on $\mathbb{C}^n$, and $I$ be the ideal of a linear subspace $\mathbb{C}^k \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ (thus $I$ is generated by $n-k$ polynomials of degree $1$). Let moreover $J$ be an ideal, and suppose that the following holds:

1. $\mathbb{C}[u] / J$ has Krull dimension at least $n-k$;
2. $\mathbb{C}[u] / (I+J)$ has Krull dimension equal to $0$.

Is it sufficient to show that the $n-k$ generators of $I$ form a regular sequence in $\mathbb{C}[u] / J$ ? If yes, what is the argument ? Is the fact that these generators are homogeneous (since $\mathbb{C}^k \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is linear) important ?

Comment: No. Take $n=2$, $k=1$,  $J=(u_1^2,u_1u_2)$, $I=(u_2)$. Then 1. and 2. are satisfied, but $u_2$ is a zero divisor in $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What would be a sufficient additional condition then ?

Comment: I think that $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$ Cohen-Macaulay is sufficient.

Comment: Suppose that it is indeed Cohen-Macaulay. Don’t we need the dimension to be equal (and not at least) $n-k$ ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't make that explicit.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but I don't understand what conditions are sufficient and necessary. Is it enough that $\mathbb{C}[u] / J$ has dimension $n-k$, or does it need to have dimension $n-k$ and be CM, given the two points above ?

Comment: It needs dimension $n-k$ **and** CM, as shown by my counter-example.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a kind of geometric interpretation of being Macaulay ? In terms of the zero set of $J$ for instance ?